# Update functionality not working as expected

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data

I am new in Spring MVC with Hibernate. I wrote a simple application but I am not getting what's wrong in this code.

The update functionality is not working properly. Upto GET method its working fine, below is the URL for the same:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestSample/forms/updateReq/1
```

After clicking the submit button, the POST method is not working. Here is the link:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestSample/forms/updateReq/addReqNo
```

This is my controller:

```
package com.sample.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.objenesis.instantiator.perc.PercSerializationInstantiator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.sample.Service.AddMoreService;
import com.sample.model.AddMoreList;
import com.sample.model.AddMoreModel;
import com.sample.model.AddNoOfReq;

@Controller
public class AddMoreFieldController {

    @Autowired
    private AddMoreService addMoreService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addReqNo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testPage(AddNoOfReq addNoOfReq, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("addNoOfReq", addNoOfReq);
        model.addAttribute("reqList", addMoreService.getReq(addNoOfReq));
        return "testPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addReqNo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testPageProcess(@ModelAttribute AddNoOfReq addNoOfReq, Model model) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= addNoOfReq.getReqName(); i++) {
            if (addNoOfReq.getReqNo() == 0) {
                addMoreService.addReq(addNoOfReq);
            } else {
                addMoreService.updateReq(addNoOfReq);
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("addNoOfReq", addNoOfReq);

        model.addAttribute("reqList", addMoreService.getReq(addNoOfReq));
        return "redirect:/forms/testPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateReq/{reqNo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editReq(@PathVariable("reqNo") int reqNo, Model model) {

        AddNoOfReq addNoOfReq = new AddNoOfReq();
        model.addAttribute("addNoOfReq", addMoreService.findElementById(reqNo));
        model.addAttribute("reqList", addMoreService.getReq(addNoOfReq));

        return "testPage";
    }
}
```

And this is my DAO:

```
package com.sample.Dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sample.model.AddMoreModel;
import com.sample.model.AddNoOfReq;

@Repository
public class AddMoreDaoImpl implements AddMoreDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(AddMoreModel addMoreModel) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addReq(AddNoOfReq addNoOfReq) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        if (addNoOfReq != null) {
            session.saveOrUpdate(addNoOfReq);

            tx.commit();

            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AddNoOfReq findElementById(int rId) {
        AddNoOfReq addNoOfReq = (AddNoOfReq) getSession().get(AddNoOfReq.class, rId);
        return addNoOfReq;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateReq(AddNoOfReq addNoOfReq) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        if (addNoOfReq != null) {
            session.update(addNoOfReq);

            tx.commit();

            session.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List getReq(AddNoOfReq addNoOfReq) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<AddNoOfReq> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from AddNoOfReq");

        list = query.list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception or error ?

Comment: No, I am not getting any exception but I am getting server 405 status as Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: Instead of **@ModelAttribute** , use **@Requestbody**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but still its not working.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't working beacuse you don't have mapping for this path:

http://localhost:8080/TestSample/forms/updateReq/addReqNo

To execute POST method ot this URL you need function like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateReq/{reqNo}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editReq(@PathVariable("reqNo") int reqNo, Model model) {

    AddNoOfReq addNoOfReq = new AddNoOfReq();
    model.addAttribute("addNoOfReq", addMoreService.findElementById(reqNo));
    model.addAttribute("reqList", addMoreService.getReq(addNoOfReq));

    return "testPage";
}
```

But you have the same only with method = RequestMethod.GET.

Comment: I am redirecting on the same form, so I am calling the same POST method for update the values.

Comment: Generally if you want to update something (name of function editReq suggests that) you should use only POST/PUT method. Even if you are using the same URL, in your REST API you should use GET methods only te receive some information not update, and another methods according to their specification. In this case: I see that your editReq method doesn't edit anything so it's GET request. Name "editReq" and url path "/updateReq/{reqNo}" are misleading. (As I said if you really need to update something change "method" atrribute).

Comment: I got it. Thank you